# Migration fails to copy any node

Tags: 8, migrations, debugging

I am trying to migrate a measily 200nodes from a Drupal 6 site to the latest Drupal 8. The web based Migrate seems to be partially working in that I have the users migrated, content types, but none of the content/nodes did. I get these errors.

> Operation on Node revisions (page) failed
>
> Migration d6_node_revision:page did not meet the requirements. Missing migrations d6_node:page. requirements: d6_node:page.

> Operation on Nodes (page) failed
>
> Migration d6_node:page did not meet the requirements. Missing migrations d6_user. requirements: d6_user.

I am also quite often getting an AJAX timeout after less than 60 seconds. I don't know if one is causing the other or what. It sounds like they are separate problems.

(I am using Krystal hosting in the UK. I can pick whatever PHP I want; I tried 5.6 and 7.2.) The web server is Lightwave, I think.

I don't really know what to do with this as I don't really know what that message means.

Do you have any suggestion for diagnosing more and getting a better understanding of the problem?

PS: This evening I successfully migrated a Drupal 7 site to Drupal 8, but using a different host.

Answer (score 1):

In migrations, programmatically you can make requirements so a migration cannot be ran until another migration has already been ran (migrated).

> Operation on Nodes (page) failed followed by Migration d6_node:page
>   did not meet the requirements. **Missing migrations d6_user.
>   requirements: d6_user.**

So what this error is saying is you need to run `d6_user` first; before you can run `d6_node:page`.

Why you might ask? Because nodes have authors, so the user's need to be already migrated so the node can set the authors. Otherwise, you would end up with nodes that don't have authors.

> Migration d6_node_revision:page did not meet the requirements. **Missing
>   migrations d6_node:page. requirements: d6_node:page.**

Like wise here, you can't have a revision until a node exists. So you need to run `d6_node:page` before running `d6_node_revision:page`

Comment: But I am using the web interface and I don't seem to have any option for changing the order of what gets migrated.

Comment: @AlexMcLintock in the UI (user interface) you should see a list of all the migrations you can do, next to them there is an execute button. You need to look for the Users and execute them first.

Answer (score 0):

Of the errors reported the one to sort out first is d6_user. Check the logs for any errors concerning the user migration? If you can use drush, you can `drush mmsg d6_user` to display the error messages.